# The determinant of a special matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Recently, I encounter the problem of calculating the determinant of the following matrix $$\left(\begin{array}{cccc} \sin(\theta_1) & \sin(\theta_1 + \delta_1) & \cdots & \sin(\theta_1 + (n-1) \delta_1)\\ \sin(\theta_2) & \sin(\theta_2 + \delta_2) & \cdots & \sin(\theta_2 + (n-1) \delta_2) \\ \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\\sin(\theta_n) & \sin(\theta_n + \delta_n) & \cdots & \sin(\theta_n + (n-1) \delta_n) \end{array}\right).$$

Is there an easy way to get its determinant? Thanks!